# JavaScript redirect causes undesired search engine results

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, feature-detection

I have an HTML5 demo site (http://html5beats.com/) that uses JavaScript to detect certain HTML5 features.  I do a redirect to a "please change or upgrade your browser" page if those features are not present, since they are critical to making the site work.

The problem is that some search engines (specifically Google) seem to follow the redirect.  This results in a nasty "Your Browser is Not Supported" message as the main search result for my site.

Am I using JavaScript redirects incorrectly?  Is there something I can do to tell Google and other search engines which page has the main site content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use `robots.txt` to tell search engines those pages that you don't want listed:

- http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449

Second, you can also provide assistance to Google (and other search engines) in understanding your site by providing a sitemap:

- http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156184

Third, you can also consider a quick-and-dirty method of catching the Google bot (and other web crawlers) through the `navigator.userAgent` property in JavaScript and preventing the redirect in those cases:

- http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

In the last case, don't do a direct comparison of the `navigator.userAgent` string. Rather, use `indexOf` to find the identifying URL in the user-agent string, e.g.:

```
function upgradeRedirect() {
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("http://www.google.com/bot.html") != -1) return;
 document.location.href = 'upgrade.html';
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions!  I've been avoiding userAgent to detect features, but it looks like a good supplement to the other 2 techniques you mentioned for giving hints to Web crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to the content you are serving to Googlebot given the user-agent they are crawling with. Perhaps a better strategy would be to load your regular content with your regular title tag etc. and then pop a modal dialogue over the page if the user doesn't support html5 with some links to download an html5 browser. That way your listing will still look respectable for site:http://html5beats.com/. BTW -- I really like your site/idea.

Comment: This is an interesting alternative.  However, the reason I redirect (and the reason the script is inline) is to avoid loading other scripts and resources that can't be used anyway.

Comment: You could load the resources a-synchronously (js/html/images), once you've already detected they are non html5 compatible.